# Trying to access property from another class Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two classes, Class1 (UIViewController) and Class2 (NSObject). In Class2 I have a property, timerCount, that is increased by 1 every 4th second. I want to set that value to a label in Class1, but it only returns 0. But directly in the Class2 it returns the correct value.

**Class2.h**

```
@property (nonatomic) int timerCount;
```

**Class2.m**

```
@synthesize timerCount;

- (void)timerStart {

    self.timerCount = 0;
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerIncrement) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
}

- (void)timerIncrement {

    self.timerCount = self.timerCount+1;

    Class1 *cls1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];
    [cls1 updateTimeLabel];
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.timerCount]); //logs correct numbers
}
```

**Class1.m**

```
- (void)updateTimeLabel {

    Class2 *cls2 = [[Class2 alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cls2.timerCount]);  //logs 0 every 4 second
}
```

So my question is, what could be wrong?

**UPDATE**
Class2.m

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

    //initialize the timer and start it
    cls1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];
    self.timerCount = 0;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerIncrement) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
}

- (void)timerIncrement {
    self.timerCount = self.timerCount-1;

    [cls1 updateTimeLeftLabel];

    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"IAP: %i", self.timerCount]);
}
```

Class1.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    cls2 = [[Class2 alloc] init];
}

- (void)updateTimeLeftLabel
{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cls2.timerCount]);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new, temporary **Class2** object in your `updateTimeLabel` method. You should be referencing the original **Class2** object that is running the timer.

Comment: How do I refer to that object? @Guy Kogus

Comment: Okay, so how do you do it?

Comment: `Class1` should have a property of type `Class2` that it can reference. Just like you have the property `timerCount`, add another property: `@property (nonatomic, strong) Class2 cls2;`

Answer (score 1):

You should not create each time new instance. That is only reason you are receiving 0. Because each new instance point to new address.

Create only single instance and use it.

Comment: I just initialised the two instances of each class in the viewDidLoad instead so that they are only created once

Comment: You should initialise only one time to Class2 also.

Comment: Okey no it doesn't work anyway. Could it be like the above answer? could you please answer my comment to that answer